How to apply the same FFMPEG slide transition for every slide in a sequence?
I have an ffmpeg command to create an MP4 video from a sequence of N x JPEG slides.  That is, I do not know how many slides there are in the sequence, it is just a directory of JPEG-s.
I'd like to apply a common slide transition for every slide in the sequence.  All the examples I've read seem to need to know how many slides there are before the filter is written.  The idea is to use one (simple) transition/filter for every slide.
So far the script looks like this:
    play_duration="-framerate 1/10"      #   10 seconds for testing

    ffmpeg                                          \
        ${play_duration}                            \
        -pattern_type glob                          \
        -i "./slides/*.jpg"                         \
                                                    \
         -c:v libx264                                \
         -filter_complex                             \
            "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2; fade=out:120:30"         \
                                                    \
        ./Slideshow.mp4

The first filter: "pad=..." is necessary to deal with inconsistiencies in the JPEG input.
My limited appreciation here is that the "fade=out:120:30" filter ought to work if I didn't need to also have the pad= construct.
Example transition examples for I've come across so far -- there are a great many variations on the same pattern -- all look a lot like this ...
    ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 3 -framerate 60 -i image1.jpg -loop 1 -t 3   \
        -framerate 60 -i image2.jpg -loop 1 -t 3 -framerate 60 -i image3.jpg   \
        -filter_complex                                             \
            "[0]scale=1920:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1280:-1:-1[s0]; [1]scale=1920:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1280:-1:-1[s1]; [2]scale=1920:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1280:-1:-1[s2]; [s0][s1]xfade=transition=circleopen:duration=1:offset=2[f0]; [f0][s2]xfade=transition=circleopen:duration=1:offset=4"                 \
        -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p                                \
        output.mp4



from: How to Create a Slideshow from Images using FFmpeg, as a representative example.

The requirement is to have the same filter/transition which will apply to all slide changes.  It sounded so easy at first.

ffmpeg -framerate 1/10 -i foo-%02d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4 Your files have to be foo-01.jpg  foo-02.jpg and so on.  Increment %02d for more places out. foo-001.jpg = %03d.

@JayCravens ... thank you for that option. Yes, the files are so numbered sequentially. Unfortunately that syntax causes a number of errors.  The two biggest are that overwrites the input JPG files and crashes with a scaling error.

Please note that the ffmpeg command above works as intened without a "fade filter".  I'm interested in resolving the requirement to have a common transition for the working command shown.  Basically just how to replace the "fade"  filter bit.

It is dissappointing that instead of applying a "common transition filter", there seems to be a preference to enumerate every single input.  I'm can resort to that kind of brute-force approach (sometimes you just have to do that).  The goal is to apply a common filter -- If that is possible.  If not possible, the definitive answer would be "No. Can't be done that way."

I agree. I know a lot of ffmpeg. Enough not to say it can't be done. It might be possible without the pre-conversion, but I don't know how. There's no difference in output, honestly. When the input files from -i foo-%02d.jpg are processed, ffmpeg is doing the same thing. It's in a temporary buffer, you can't see it happening.  The order is different. It will make the video, apply both fades, then add it to it's -concat list, each file.  This just processes all files through each step once, instead of all three at once, before concatenation. They are completely identical output files.

Don't let odd numbered WxH's anywhere near ffmpeg. Just pre-procces the image size and save yourself the headache.
Using -vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" to avoid "not divisible by 2" works, at first, but it's error prone and seems unreliable.
So, I made a function to prepare the images, leaving only video for ffmpeg to handle.  Default is 1080p.
#!/bin/bash

process_images() {
    file_list=(*.jpg)
    for jpeg_file in "${file_list[@]}"; do

        source_height=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$jpeg_file")
        if (( source_height % 2 != 0 )); then
            target_height=$((source_height - 1))
        else
            target_height=$source_height
        fi

        source_width=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$jpeg_file")
        if (( source_width % 2 != 0 )); then
            target_width=$((source_width - 1))
        else
            target_width=$source_width
        fi

        echo "$jpeg_file" "$target_width"x"$target_height"
        convert "$jpeg_file" -resize "$target_width"x"$target_height" new_"$jpeg_file"

    done
}

make_videos() {
  target_height=1080

  file_list=(new_*.jpg)
  for post_jpeg in "${file_list[@]}"; do
    filename="${post_jpeg%.*}"

   ffmpeg -hide_banner -framerate 1/10 -i "$post_jpeg" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -r 30 -crf 12 -avoid_negative_ts auto "$filename".mkv && rm "$post_jpeg" 
  done
}

fade_in() {
    file_list1=(in_*.mkv)
        echo "Executing fade_in"
        for file1 in "${file_list1[@]}"; do
            ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$file1" -vf fade=in:0:30 -crf 12 -preset fast "out_$file1"
        done
    mv in_*.mkv ./temp
}

fade_out() {
    file_list2=(out_*.mkv)
    echo "Executing fade_out"
    for file2 in "${file_list2[@]}"; do
        frame_count=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_packets -show_entries stream=nb_read_packets -of csv=p=0 "$file2")
        frame_start=$((frame_count - 30))
        ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$file2" -vf fade=out:"$frame_start":30 -crf 12 -preset fast "to_mux_$file2"
    done
    mv out_in_*.mkv ./temp
}

process_images
make_videos

mkdir -p ./temp

for file in *.mkv; do
    mv "$file" "in_$file"
done

fade_in
fade_out

ls --quoting-style=shell-always -1v *.mkv > tmp.txt
sed 's/^/file /' tmp.txt > list.txt && rm tmp.txt

ffmpeg -hide_banner -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -avoid_negative_ts auto -movflags +faststart "muxed_final.mkv"

mv to_mux_*.mkv ./temp

rm -rf ./temp list.txt

exit 0

Save as: sshow_fade.sh
Change mode executable: chmod +x sshow_fade.sh
Usage: ./sshow_fade.sh
Run the script inside the folder with the jpeg files.
The fade duration is in frames. fade=in:0:30 fade=out:"$frame_start":30The 30 is 1 second, 60 for 2 seconds etc.
I already had the fade in/out script. My idea: make each image a video first.Then use the fade effect on the video's & concatenate.
The jpeg's I used and the video. It looks good.
Update 2: The above link has a .zip demonstrating how to add audio to each slide, with example.  I figured, why not, it's the only thing missing other than captions.  I'll add those also, since convert will add text with ease.

Alas, there is only one frame.  I did attempt that fade syntax, it may have "worked", and looked jittery.  The "divisible by 2" issue is resolved by: "-vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2"

Jittery?  That my be what -vsync 0 does, I've seen it used here, but never noticed any difference in my output. ffmpeg -vsync 0... is worth a shot, though.  It does something ;-)

Looks as if Kubuntu doesn't have convert ... I presume it is the one from imagemagick

@will Sometimes you have to use the magick command instead.  They are synonymous.

One thing, this term: vf="scale=$scaled_wid ..." in make_videos(), is never used.  Was that a typo or did you intend to use it in the following ffmpeg command?

Good call!  Yes, it's supposed to be in the arguments. I had changed the method of calculation quite a few times, and it looks like I didn't put it back!  Excellent find.  That will keep even 4:3 AR's and odd sized images at the proper viewing scale.

I have an error in make_videos():  "[NULL @ 0x55c428870480] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:431:431' scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:431:431: Invalid argument"

Hmm. Take the $vf out of the ffmpeg arguments, it will run.  I will check it out.  It will likely also run if you just remove the 2 padding values from the end.  I'll try to find why it returned an odd value.

Don't worry about that.  It looks like a typo on the -vf flag.  Runs to the end, but witin some messages I'm tracking down.

@will Yes, it does run, at first.  Then, same as pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2... It's error prone. Now, I'm getting Value -29.000000 for parameter 'start_frame' out of range [0 - 2.14748e+09]. It works flawlessly when I take it out.  Jumping from 400x400 to 1920x1080... I can't make it fail.  Seems that removal wins.

bash script:
#!/bin/bash
LST=(*.jpg)
f="${LST[0]}"
XFO=3   #duration of pic
XFD=0.5 #duration of transition
INP=("-loop" "1" "-t" "$XFO" "-i" "$f")
echo $f
PDX="[v0]"
OFS=0
WID=320
HEI=180
SPS="scale=$WID:$HEI:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=$WID:$HEI:-1:-1,setsar=1"
FLS="
[0]$SPS[v0];
"
FLX=""
for (( i=1; i<${#LST[*]}; i++ )); do
  f="${LST[$i]}"
  INP+=("-loop" "1" "-t" "$XFO" "-i" "$f")
  OFS=$(echo "$OFS + $XFO - $XFD" | bc -l)
  FLS+="[$i]$SPS[v$i];
"
  FLX+="${PDX}[v${i}]xfade=duration=$XFD:offset=${OFS}:transition=custom:expr='if(gt(P-mod(PI*(P+ceil(Y/20)*(ceil(Y/20)-P+PI)),1)*0.15,X/W),A,B)'"
  PDX="[x${i}]"
  FLX+="${PDX};
"
  echo $OFS $f
done
ffmpeg "${INP[@]}" -filter_complex "$FLS $FLX" -map $PDX -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 20 /tmp/output.mp4 -y -hide_banner
mpv /tmp/output.mp4


This is neat.  A complex argument construction.  That's some awesome & very advanced filter use.  If there was ever proof there's more than one way to skin a cat, these two scripts are it!

@Баяр Гончикжапов ... Basically this snippet builds a sequence of transformation tuples.  I appreciate the cleverness involved.  I'm almost convinced that there is no facility for a "parameterised filter" to be applied to all images, alas.

@Баяр Гончикжапов ... I think it is interesting to have line-breaks in strings.  Also, you can just escapt the new-line if you want, as: FLX+="${PDX};\n"  for example.

Error message:  "'[swscaler @ 0x6083db211a80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly'"; some debugging to do ;-)  Using: ffmpeg version 6.0-6ubuntu1.

Newlines was added for tracing, do echo ffmpeg ... instead of just run ffmpeg .... Now, newlines can be removed. But, I don't care ))) just copy and paste.
